# Using gpio pins of raspberry pi to control a fan

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I was wondering if it is possible to control my fan (attached to the raspberry pi board) via the GPIO pins.

Basically, I would like to have a script which monitors the temperature of the chip
and turn on the fan when beyond 45'C for instance. 
My fan is externally powered with 12v AC.

Is it possible to use the GPIO pins as a switch.

Comment: Perhaps better suited @ http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

As @Fredrick says, this question is more suited to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Since you're switching an AC load, A relay is the easiest solution.

You can switch a mechanical relay using a small transistor, but you will hear this click on and off which can be annoying.

Another option is a solidstate relay which will switch silently, but are more expensive

Answer (score 2):

You can "switch" it with a relay: http://www.susa.net/wordpress/2012/06/raspberry-pi-relay-using-gpio/

Here is some instructions on how to program it with Python: http://lwk.mjhosting.co.uk/?p=343

As gnibbler noted (thanks!), The second link is about a rev1 board. If you have a rev2 board, some of the GPIO pins have changed. elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals

Comment: Note the the second link is about a rev1 board. If you have a rev2 board, some of the GPIO pins have changed. http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals

Comment: You're completely right. That's the board I have so didn't think about it. I edited in that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CPU temperature with:

```bash
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

The command above returns a value such as `temp=49.4'C` which can be parsed to a float for example with

```bash
temp=$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | cut -f2 -d= | cut -f1 -d\')

echo $temp
### output: 49.4
```

Next,

1. Get a relay like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2027291228.html) or similar.
2. Connect the gpio pins as shown in [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-Any-Device-Using-a-Raspberry-Pi-and-a-/), [this](https://electronicshobbyists.com/controlling-ac-devices-with-raspberry-pi-raspberry-pi-relay-control/), or [this article](https://www.electronicshub.org/control-a-relay-using-raspberry-pi/). Let's assume you used GPIO pin **21**.
3. Use a control script like this one:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys
from RPi import GPIO

pin = 21

# GPIO setup; GPIO Numbers instead of board numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(chan, GPIO.OUT)


GPIO.output(chan, GPIO.HIGH)  # Turn on

time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(chan, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn off

GPIO.cleanup()
```

As an alternative you can use the **`gpio`** command line (comes with the `wiringpi` package):

```bash
gpio -g mode 21 out
gpio -g write 21 1   ## TURN ON
gpio -g write 21 0   ## TUNR OFF
```

> NOTE: The relay has three connectors allowing you to use it either in *normally on* mode or *normally off* mode. You can can switch modes by using either the left of right connector (relative to the central one). If you use the *normally on* mode then the relay will be on at LOW `0` and off at HIGH `1`, i.e. then your relay will be switched on even when the pi is powered down.